# Set value in null cell in row with a non-null value in any other following rows

Tags: sql-server

I have data retrieved from query in this format

```
  Day   Module1     Module2     Module3      Module3    IPQC
    1   TestData1   NULL        NULL         NULL       NULL
    1   NULL        TestData2   NULL         NULL       NULL
    1   NULL        NULL        TestDAta3    NULL       NULL
    1   NULL        NULL        NULL         NULL       TestData4
    2   NULL        NULL        NULL         TestData16 NULL
    2   TestData5   NULL        NULL         NULL       NULL
    2   NULL        NULL        TestDAta6    NULL       NULL
    2   NULL        NULL        NULL         NULL       TestData8
    3   NULL        NULL        NULL         TestData10 NULL
    3   NULL        NULL        NULL         NULL       TestData11
```

Now I want above data in following format

```
    Day Module1     Module2     Module3      Module3    IPQC
    1   TestData1   TestData2   TestDAta3    NULL       TestData4
    2   TestData5   NULL        TestDAta6    TestData16 TestData8
    3   NULL        NULL        NULL         TestData10 TestData11
```

Please help me as soon as possible if anyone knows how to do it.
Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: What's the algorithm for your desired output?

Comment: Post the query that gave you the first result please.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `Aggregate` to columns

```
SELECT [Day],
       Module1 = Max(Module1),
       Module2 = Max(Module2),
       Module3 = Max(Module3),
       Module4 = Max(Module4),
       IPQC = Max(IPQC)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY [DAY]
```

Comment: Thanks VR46. I am sorry that I forgot to say that columns I have given are dynamic. there may be more or less columns. Only the column Day is fix but Module1,Module2,Module3, Module4 and IPQC are dynamic columns. There may come different column names in any numbers. I have used

select @cols=Stuff((select ','+quotename(production_module_id) from pl_production_schedule
where production_plan_id=@plan_id
group by production_module_id order by production_module_id
for xml path(''),type).value('.','Nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')


 to retrieve columns

Comment: your solution worked well, but I have no idea how to implement it in dynamic columns.

Comment: @user3773521  - Can you add the source query. I think we can fix that query

Comment: My query is long enough that is not allowed here due to it's length. I am supposed to get help from one brother here.... Let's see.  And thanks. It worked for static columns.